# Error while making movie from png's with avconv or ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, avconv

I want to create a movie from a bunch of png's by using the command:

```
avconv -i pics/*.png  out.mp4
```

or

```
ffmpeg -r 1/1 -start_number 1 -i pics/*.png -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

However, in both cases I get:

```
Error while opening encoder for output stream #18:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

The complete log message for the second command is:

```
ffmpeg version 1.0.10 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
built on Jul 25 2014 07:50:40 with gcc 4.7 (Debian 4.7.2-5)
configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-cflags='-g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security ' --extra-ldflags='Wl,-z,relro' --cc='ccache cc' --enable-shared --enable-libmp3lame --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-libfaac --enable-libxvid --enable-postproc --enable-x11grab --enable-libgsm --enable-libtheora --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libx264 --enable-libspeex --enable-nonfree --disable-stripping --enable-libvpx --enable-libschroedinger --disable-encoder=libschroedinger --enable-version3 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-avfilter --enable-libfreetype --enable-libvo-aacenc --disable-decoder=amrnb --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libaacplus --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --disable-vda --enable-libbluray --enable-libcdio --enable-gnutls --enable-frei0r --enable-openssl --enable-libass --enable-libopus --enable-fontconfig --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libdc1394 --disable-altivec --dis  libavutil      51. 73.101 / 51. 73.101
libavcodec     54. 59.100 / 54. 59.100
libavformat    54. 29.104 / 54. 29.104
libavdevice    54.  2.101 / 54.  2.101
libavfilter     3. 17.100 /  3. 17.100
libswscale      2.  1.101 /  2.  1.101
libswresample   0. 15.100 /  0. 15.100
libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
Input #0, image2, from 'pics/1.png':
Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgba, 594x557, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
File 'output.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
height not divisible by 2 (594x557)
Output #0, image2, to 'pics/10.png':
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgba, 594x557, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 1 tbc
Output #1, image2, to 'pics/11.png':
    Stream #1:0: Video: png, rgba, 594x557, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 1 tbc
Output #2, image2, to 'pics/12.png':
    Stream #2:0: Video: png, rgba, 594x557, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 1 tbc
Output #3, image2, to 'pics/13.png':
    Stream #3:0: Video: png, rgba, 594x557, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 1 tbc
Output #4, image2, to 'pics/14.png':
    Stream #4:0: Video: png, rgba, 594x557, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 1 tbc
Output #5, image2, to 'pics/15.png':
    Stream #5:0: Video: png, rgba, 594x557, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 1 tbc
Output #6, image2, to 'pics/16.png':
    Stream #6:0: Video: png, rgba, 594x557, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 1 tbc
Output #7, image2, to 'pics/17.png':
    Stream #7:0: Video: png, rgba, 594x557, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 1 tbc
Output #8, image2, to 'pics/18.png':
    Stream #8:0: Video: png, rgba, 594x557, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 1 tbc
Output #9, image2, to 'pics/19.png':
    Stream #9:0: Video: png, rgba, 594x557, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 1 tbc
Output #10, image2, to 'pics/2.png':
    Stream #10:0: Video: png, rgba, 594x557, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 1 tbc
Output #11, image2, to 'pics/3.png':
    Stream #11:0: Video: png, rgba, 594x557, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 1 tbc
Output #12, image2, to 'pics/4.png':
    Stream #12:0: Video: png, rgba, 594x557, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 1 tbc
Output #13, image2, to 'pics/5.png':
    Stream #13:0: Video: png, rgba, 594x557, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 1 tbc
Output #14, image2, to 'pics/6.png':
    Stream #14:0: Video: png, rgba, 594x557, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 1 tbc
Output #15, image2, to 'pics/7.png':
    Stream #15:0: Video: png, rgba, 594x557, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 1 tbc
Output #16, image2, to 'pics/8.png':
    Stream #16:0: Video: png, rgba, 594x557, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 1 tbc
Output #17, image2, to 'pics/9.png':
    Stream #17:0: Video: png, rgba, 594x557, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 1 tbc
Output #18, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
    Stream #18:0: Video: h264, yuv420p, 594x557, q=-1--1, 90k tbn, 30 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (png -> png)
  Stream #0:0 -> #1:0 (png -> png)
  Stream #0:0 -> #2:0 (png -> png)
  Stream #0:0 -> #3:0 (png -> png)
  Stream #0:0 -> #4:0 (png -> png)
  Stream #0:0 -> #5:0 (png -> png)
  Stream #0:0 -> #6:0 (png -> png)
  Stream #0:0 -> #7:0 (png -> png)
  Stream #0:0 -> #8:0 (png -> png)
  Stream #0:0 -> #9:0 (png -> png)
  Stream #0:0 -> #10:0 (png -> png)
  Stream #0:0 -> #11:0 (png -> png)
  Stream #0:0 -> #12:0 (png -> png)
  Stream #0:0 -> #13:0 (png -> png)
  Stream #0:0 -> #14:0 (png -> png)
  Stream #0:0 -> #15:0 (png -> png)
  Stream #0:0 -> #16:0 (png -> png)
  Stream #0:0 -> #17:0 (png -> png)
  Stream #0:0 -> #18:0 (png -> libx264)
Error while opening encoder for output stream #18:0 - maybe incorrect      parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text with asterisk needs the sequential digit indicator %d instead, I think:

```
avconv -i 'pics/%d.png'  out.mp4
ffmpeg -r 1/1 -start_number 1 -i 'pics/%d.png' -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

quoting from avconv man page:

```
   The pattern may contain the string "%d" or "%0Nd", which specifies the position of the characters representing a
   sequential number in each filename matched by the pattern. If the form "%d0Nd" is used, the string representing
   the number in each filename is 0-padded and N is the total number of 0-padded digits representing the number.
   The literal character '%' can be specified in the pattern with the string "%%".

   If the pattern contains "%d" or "%0Nd", the first filename of the file list specified by the pattern must
   contain a number inclusively contained between 0 and 4, all the following numbers must be sequential. This
   limitation may be hopefully fixed.

   The pattern may contain a suffix which is used to automatically determine the format of the images contained in
   the files.

   For example the pattern "img-%03d.bmp" will match a sequence of filenames of the form img-001.bmp, img-002.bmp,
   ..., img-010.bmp, etc.; the pattern "i%%m%%g-%d.jpg" will match a sequence of filenames of the form i%m%g-1.jpg,
   i%m%g-2.jpg, ..., i%m%g-10.jpg, etc.

   The size, the pixel format, and the format of each image must be the same for all the files in the sequence.

   The following example shows how to use avconv for creating a video from the images in the file sequence
   img-001.jpeg, img-002.jpeg, ..., assuming an input framerate of 10 frames per second:

           avconv -i 'img-%03d.jpeg' -r 10 out.mkv
```